# Handle errors using a custom view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I want to handle custom errors like 401, 403, 500 etc in Spring 3.2 application using `Filters` . I do not want to use the web.xml approach of defining the error pages.

I tried to follow the solution listed at [How to handle exceptions thrown while rendering a view in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245932/how-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-while-rendering-a-view-in-spring-mvc)

But ErrorHandler.handle does not really exist.

How can I use filters to catch all the errors and redirect to different views ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle exceptions in Spring Controllers is using the @ExceptionHanldler @ControllerAdvice annotations. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers) is the relevant part of the documentation and here is a tutorial on [their](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/) usage.

Comment: I did it ... Its apt for most of my needs too ..but i want it to not work for one Exception class ... how can I exclude that exception class from @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) annotation

Comment: You can add a second @ExceptionHandler(MyOTherException.class) which will handle only that case. The handler that you have already added will take care of all the other exceptions.