# How i can print stacktrace from my java class to a servlet

Tags: java

i want to print the stack trace on my jsp page. I am calling a method from my servlet for sending a mail but when some issue occurs it still executes my next line.The next i have called a success page
It always goes to that page \

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Properly Handle Exceptions in a JSP/Servlet App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182771/how-to-properly-handle-exceptions-in-a-jsp-servlet-app)

Comment: "but when some issue occurs it still executes my next line."  You need to rethrow or wrap-and-throw the exception if you do not want to continue in the current scope.  Otherwise, catching exceptions means you will continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a log framework such as slf4j or log4j instead. Displaying the stack trace in your results is not helpful to the end user and may be a security risk. Catch the appropriate exceptions and log them, or use framework features (as provided by Spring and other frameworks) to automatically log exceptions for you and return an error page.

Comment: @user2735082 (1) Use the @ in replies; it notifies the user. (2) You can use whatever tools you like; I just prefer Spring. If you don't use a framework that does exception handling, you have to do it yourself.